# Best 100% pure Java media framework

Tags: java, media

Im looking for a pure java media framework primarily for playback. Supported formats should be (at least) wav, midi, and maybe ogg  vorbis. Ideally it would also support more advanced features like volume control, mixing and the like. Can you please suggest something that will meet these requirements?

Comment: have you tried Java Media Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [JMF (Java Media Framework)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) ?

Comment: I had heard that this library is basically unsupported now. Is that true?

Comment: @user1164112 I never heard about it, where did you found that?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use standard [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) and found it working quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Use java [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) for Media. [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) features :

- Audio file formats: AIFF, AU and WAV
- Music file formats: MIDI Type 0, MIDI Type 1, and Rich Music Format (RMF)
- Sound formats: 8-bit and 16-bit audio data, in mono and stereo, with sample rates from 8 kHz to 48 kHz
- Linear, a-law, and mu-law encoded data in any of the supported audio file formats
- MIDI wavetable synthesis and sequencing in software, and access to hardware MIDI devices
- An all-software mixer that can mix and render up to 64 total channels of digital audio and synthesized MIDI music

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/sound/).